# PHP If Else issue - always return blank

Tags: php, if-statement

Stupid question time.

This if statement always shows nothing.

```
$new = 'test = new user id';

if (stripos($new, 'test') !== FALSE) {
    $chk = explode("=",$new);
    $chk = $chk[1];
    echo $chk;
} else {
    $chk = '';
}

echo $chk;
```

When I echo `$chk` within the if else it shows the correct value, but the final echo is always blank.

Why?

Shouldn't `$chk = "new user id"` if the string contains that?

Also is there a neater more succinct way of writing this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to perform fine for me: http://3v4l.org/blkhW

Comment: For me its getting  fine

Comment: Could you provide the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code. it works fine.

```
$new = 'test = new user id';

if (stripos($new, 'test') === FALSE) {
        $chk = '';

    } else {
          $chk = explode("=",$new);
        $chk = $chk[1];


    }

    echo $chk;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize $chk before your condition statement.

```
$new = 'test = new user id';
$chk = '';
if (stripos($new, 'test') !== FALSE) {
        $chk = explode("=",$new);
        $chk = $chk[1];
        echo $chk;
    } else {
        $chk = '';
    }

    echo $chk;
```

Comment: And how this relate's to the question asked by OP's ?

Comment: Why do you *think* this answers the question at all? What does it fix? It initializes a variable, which isn't necessary at all.

Comment: That is always a good idea, but it won't help here simply because he is changing $chk in both blocks...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
    $new = 'test = new user id';
    $start = strpos($new,'=')?strpos($new,'='):strlen($new);
    echo substr($new,$start +1);
?>
```